# initialize html controls in asp.net

Tags: asp.net

If I have an html input `"<input id="score1" type="text" value=""/>"` and want to initialize it on the c# page load, but I don't want to use asp controls.How do I do it?

Thanks

Answer (score 5):

You can use server-side plain HTML controls, by just using runat="server".

For instance:

```
<input type="text" runat="server" id="myTextBox" />

// ...and then in the code-behind...

myTextBox.Value = "harbl";
```

Comment: ...and for the record these are typically known as "Hybrid Controls" in the ASP.NET realm. Not quite HTML controls, not quite Web Controls.

Comment: I've never seen them referred to as hybrid controls. They've always been HTML Controls.

Comment: I like the "Hybrid Controls" term though

Comment: You can like it, but what if nobody else uses it?

Comment: Never heard the Hybrid Controls either, but it is a good term. Don't think I'll "switch" from saying HTML Controls though.

Answer (score 3):

<input id="score1" type="text" **runat="server"** value=""/>

Then in your page's load event:

```
score1.Value = "some value";
```

Answer (score 2):

You could set a property on the page codebehind, the access the property on the page

```
public class MyPage
{
    public string InputDefaultContent { get; set; }

    private void Page_Load(object s, EventArgs e)
    {
        InputDefaultContent = "Blah";
    }
}
```

then on the page

```
<input type="text" value="<%= InputDefaultContent %>" />
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<input type='text' value='default value' />
```